# Is it a good idea to consume Soylent meal replacements (specifically containing potassium supplements)?

Tags: nutrition, supplement, potassium, meal-replacement

The reason I am asking this is actually related to daily recommended potassium intake, which is stated to be around 4.700 mg daily. However, even if I concentrate all my meals on potassium intake, it's very hard to get near this number (I think around 14 bananas would suffice).

So searching for possible ways to increase intake, I noticed a number of "meal replacements" (like Soylent, but many of them DIY), which use potassium chloride or potassium citrate to provide the necessary intake.

For example, this ["Keto Chow" recipe](https://www.completefoods.co/diy/recipes/keto-chow-150-master-rich-chocolate) contains 6 grams of potassium citrate, and apparently perfectly provides all the nutrients:

[image: Nutrient facts for Keto Chow]
<sup>Image taken from [www.completefoods.co](https://www.completefoods.co/diy/recipes/keto-chow-150-master-rich-chocolate)</sup>

So the "numbers" look rather nice, but I am wondering:

1. Are there any downsides using such meals?
2. Specifically for potassium, is potassium citrate a safe supplement?